# How to add careers to communities

Tags: support, jobs

I don't have a Stack Overflow account but I have a careers account. How can I add it to my current communities?

I tried searching for it but it doesn't show. In the past it used to show under the "current community" tab but now it disappeared.

Comment: It *is* a part of the current community of SO.  You're now on meta.SE, which is not a part of the SO community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Careers is not a community in that sense; it is not a Stack Exchange Q&A site.

You cannot add it to the list of Stack Exchange sites; it is not listed under *More Stack Exchange Communities* either.

Instead, it is part of the *Stack Overflow* site services, like its dedicated Meta site. It is only listed in the dropdown on Stack Overflow itself. It is also listed in the footer of all Stack Exchange sites, under the *Other* header.